# Google Authentication in Angular Routing not working properly

Tags: angular, routes, google-signin

I have used Google Authentication in Login Component of my angular application. After successful authentication I am routing to Home Component using `this.router.navigate(['home']);`

the URL in my browser is getting changed from `localhost:4200/login` to `localhost:4200/home` but the HTML template of Home component is not rendered properly and also `ngOnInIt()` of Home component is not getting called.

This application is presented [here](https://github.com/kmas82/Sign-In-with-Google).

Can anyone help me to get `ngOnInIt()` called and HTML of home component rendered properly?

Reference:
[Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

Answer (score 0):

To keep code clear and simple, there's an existing Google Sign-in integration library for Angular : [ng-gapi](https://github.com/rubenCodeforges/ng-gapi). Maybe you could have a look to it, it can help you.

I'm not sure, but you are probably encountering an issue with change detection mecanism, because you're calling an external js function.
Could you have a look at [Understanding NgZone](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-ngzone)

For example, here is a portion of my code using ng-gapi and NgZone :

```
googleAuth.getAuth().subscribe(auth => {

  auth.isSignedIn.listen((isSignedIn) => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.isSignedInChanged(isSignedIn);
    });
  });
  auth.currentUser.listen((googleUser: GoogleUser) => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.currentUserChanged(googleUser);
    });
  });

  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    if (auth.isSignedIn.get() && auth.currentUser.get()) {
      this.setUser(auth.currentUser.get());
      this._isSignedIn = true
      this._isUserLoggedChange.next(true);
      this.signedIn$.next(true);
    } else {
      this.signedIn$.next(false);
    }

    this._initialized = true;
    this.initialized.next(true);
  })
})
```

As you can see, I'm using `ngZone.run` to call Angular code from callback of Google Sign-in.

Hope it will be you.

Comment: Thanks for your response.